printing without page feed (line by line) in python on dot matrix printer
I am looking for a soulution to print on a dot matrix printer and endless paper feed, without page feed. Request: every two or three minutes a (new) dataset should be printed without sending the side feed signal or anything like this.
What I tried until now:
    import win32printing
    print_font = {
        "height": 8,
    }
    with Printer(printer_name='OKI DATA CORP ML6300FB-SC', linegap=0, auto_page=False) as printer:
        printer.text("          Line1 Test!", font_config=print_font)
        printer.text("          Line2 ... data", font_config=print_font)

I tried to add win32con.DT_SINGLELINE in the win32printing.py function get_print_flag:
@classmethod
def get_print_flag(cls, align="left"):
    print_flag = win32con.DT_TOP|win32con.DT_WORDBREAK|win32con.DT_NOCLIP|win32con.DT_SINGLELINE
    

but this isn't the correct function I guess.
I have also experimented with other modules (win32print), but without any significant success.
Perhaps someone else has already had to solve this issue?
